# Google Charts stopped working - Uncaught Error: Row 14 has 2 columns, but must have 4

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

EDIT: It seems some of my raw data does not contain a value for each of the three stacked bars. This is valid and based on user choice. Example: a restaurant may have a breakfast only menu, but no Sandwiches or Light Meals (see below).

The Google Chart is falling over at this row, where there are no physical entries of ZERO for the (valid) missing user selections.

Is there a Google Charts setting whereby a "missing value" is treated as ZERO value?

Here's an example of the JSON input:

```
   [{"store_name":"Store 1","dish_menu":"Breakfast","dish_count":"13"},
    {"store_name":"Store 1","dish_menu":"Light Meals","dish_count":"7"},
    {"store_name":"Store 1","dish_menu":"Sandwiches","dish_count":"7"},
    {"store_name":"Store 2","dish_menu":"Breakfast","dish_count":"13"},
    {"store_name":"Store 2","dish_menu":"Light Meals","dish_count":"7"},
    {"store_name":"Store 2","dish_menu":"Sandwiches","dish_count":"7"},
    {"store_name":"Store 3","dish_menu":"Breakfast","dish_count":"13"},   <-- FAILS HERE
    {"store_name":"Store 4","dish_menu":"Breakfast","dish_count":"13"},
    {"store_name":"Store 4","dish_menu":"Light Meals","dish_count":"7"},
    {"store_name":"Store 4","dish_menu":"Sandwiches","dish_count":"7"},]
```

---

I have 3 Google charts on a page, 2 are pie, 1 is a stacked bar.

Today, for reasons I cannot understand, the stacked bar chart stopped working and the message inspect shows is "Error: Row 14 has 2 columns, but must have 4", and points to the bowels of Google code. This page has been in production for over a month and working just fine.

When I look at the code and compare it with last back up (which was was working OK, 2 weeks old), the code is exactly the same. Also, the SQL query output is working just fine.

Any suggestions on where to look are highly appreciated.

CODE:

```
function loadHQCharts() { 
// CHART #1 
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChartDishMix});
// CHART #2 
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChartMenuMix});
// CHART #3 
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChartStoreMix});
};

function drawChartStoreMix() {

    var url =  window.location.origin + '/tce-php/getdata.php?var=HQLOADMMS';

    jQuery.getJSON( url, function(json) {

        // convert JSON to chart required format
        var stores = _.chain(json).pluck("store_name").sort().uniq(true).value();

        var tempHTML = "";
        jQuery('#store_list').empty();

        stores.forEach(function (entry) {
            tempHTML = tempHTML + '<option value="' + entry + '">' + entry + '</option>';
        });

        /*** Load data into drop down lists here ***/
        var store_selector = document.getElementById('store_list'); 
        store_selector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tempHTML);
        /*** Load default selections for top of drop down lists here ***/
        store_selector.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<option selected="selected" value="ALL">All Stores...</option>');

        var header = _.chain(json).pluck("dish_menu").sort().uniq(true).value();
        header.unshift("Menus");

        var rows = _.chain(json)
                    .groupBy(function(item) { return item.store_name; })
                    .map(function(group, key) { 
            var result = [key];
            _.each(group, function(item) { 
                result[_.indexOf(header, item.dish_menu)] = parseInt(item.dish_count); 
            });
            return result; 
        })
        .value();

        var jsonData = [header].concat(rows);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
            title: 'Menu Mix By Store',
            titleTextStyle:{ color:'#747474', fontSize:'15', bold:false },
            isStacked: true,
            chartArea: { left: '55', top: '50', width: '88%', height: '65%' },              
            is3D: true,
            legend: { position:'top'}, 
            legendTextStyle: { color:'#747474', fontSize:'11', bold:false },
            bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
            vAxis:{ title:'', textStyle:{color: '#747474',fontSize: '11', paddingRight: '0',marginRight: '0'} },
            hAxis: { title: '', textStyle: { color: '#747474', fontSize: '11', paddingRight: '0', marginRight: '0'} }
//          vAxis: {title: '# Dishes'},
//          hAxis: {title: 'Stores'}                
//          legend: {position: 'none'},
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('fran_mix'));
        chart.draw(data, options);  

    })
    .done(function() {
    })
    .fail(function() {
    });
};
```

JSON sample:

```
[{"store_name":"Store 1","dish_menu":"Breakfast","dish_count":"13"},
{"store_name":"Store 1","dish_menu":"Light Meals","dish_count":"7"},
{"store_name":"Store 1","dish_menu":"Sandwiches","dish_count":"7"},...]
```

Comment: First, you should have a single call to `google.load` that has a single callback.  This callback can be a function that calls all of your chart drawing functions.  Second, can you update your question with a full copy of `json`?  I was able to replicate the chart with no problems given the small sample.

Comment: Hi asgallant, thanks for the reply.The reason for the three google.load calls is there are three charts being rendered in each call's callback. the page is behind a uid / pwd. Would you mind looking at the page to see what you think is the problem? How do I get to you privately (I am reasonably new on this forum!). Thanks!

Comment: @TheRealPapa, there is no way to message folks directly here, and the goal is to leave good resources for future visitors. If possible, could you try editing your code with an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to figure out the core of the problem so that we can reproduce it? That will get you an answer the fastest.

Comment: Hi @jmac, thanks. I have figured out why it is happening (see above). Google Charts seems clumsy in how it works (this is my first time using it). Is there a work around to my question above? Thanks!

Comment: I am not an expert (@asgallant plays that role here), but it would seem to be solvable if you just added blank (or zero) values for the missing items. If you try just adding the two zero value rows to your example for Store 3 (for light meals and sandwiches), it should work out fine. How you add it depends on how your data that you're grabbing is structured.

Comment: Hi @jmac, I was hoping to avoid coding ad-nauseum for what I would expect to be the obvious default value for a missing entry... Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: There is an `interpolatenulls` option that you may want to try from the docs, but I don't have the time to figure out how to test your code, so you can either give it a shot yourself, or wait for asgallant to awake from his slumber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not that the Visualization API doesn't know what to do with the missing values, it's that you aren't providing the complete structure to the DataTable constructor.  Your `jsonData` variable contains an array like this:

```
[
    ['Menus', 'Breakfast', 'Light Meals', 'Sandwiches']
    ['Store 1', 13, 7, 7],
    ['Store 2', 13, 7, 7],
    ['Store 3', 13],
    ['Store 4', 13, 7, 7]
]
```

The constructor requires that each row have the same number of columns as the DataTable (as defined by the header row, in this case).  If you replace this line:

```
var result = [key];
```

with these:

```
var result = new Array(header.length).map(function () {return null;});
result[0] = key;
```

your arrays will all be the proper length, with nulls filled in where you don't have any values.  The chart should draw fine with this.

For the API loading, replace the three calls to `google.load` with a single call:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: function () {
    drawChartDishMix();
    drawChartMenuMix();
    drawChartStoreMix();
}});
```

Comment: Hi @asgallant, GENIUS, THANKS!! Saved me the last of my hairs and sanity (as well as a tonne of time!) and learned something new.